# Python find word can be built with characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find out if the word word 'apple'(`word_list`) can be built with `char_list1` but can not be built with `char_list2`

```
word_list=['a','p','p','l','e']
char_list1=['p','a','l','f','p','e']
char_list2=['p','a','l','f','e']
```

because `char_list2` is missing a `p`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `Counter` you can easily compare the counts of occurrences of each letter

```
from collections import Counter
word = Counter(word_list)
char = Counter(char_list1)

match = True
for k, v in word.items():
    print(k, v, char[k])
    if char[k] < v:
        match = False
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on David's answer:

```
from collections import Counter
def check(word_list, char_list):
    word = Counter(word_list)
    char = Counter(char_list1)
    return all(v <= char[k] for k, v in word.items())
```